# Error "The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string." with Firebird

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, firebird, outlook-addin

I have created an Outlook 2013 add-in which is integrated with a Firebird database using Visual Studio 2013. This works totally fine, the packages which are used in this add-in are

```
EntityFramework 6.1.3
EntityFramework.Firebird 4.10.0
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient 4.10.0
```

When I converted my project to Visual Studio 2015, it give me the error shown below

**Error :**

```
The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.
Could not retrieve storage version.
```

I have also tried to update packages but this did not work. I have updated the packages to:

```
EntityFramework 6.1.3
EntityFramework.Firebird 5.0.5
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient 5.0.5
```

Comment: Do you get this error on execute or on compilation? You might want to try to install the the Firebird .net provider and Firebird DDEX provider from [the Firebird website](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/additional-downloads/). IIRC some of the Visual Studio tooling needs it to be able to work with a Firebird database; just having the nuget package isn't enough.

Comment: I get this error on execution time.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you're not connected to database or the connection string is not valid to connect to database. [This](https://github.com/cincuranet/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient/blob/master/Provider/src/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient/FirebirdClient/FbProviderServices.cs#L146) is the method that might be interesting for you.

Comment: Your link is down